# A new table per client in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Ordinarily I wouldn't consider this, but I'm wondering in what ways could this be detrimental?

My current set up:

- each client has up to approx 150 000 rows
- I'm performing fulltext searching over two columns
- the other column is the client's ID

As the table becomes bigger, searches are becoming woefully slow, even though, as most, each search only needs to be performed on 150 000 rows.

It's proving really hard to ONLY search a client's rows when using fulltext indices.

One option is to create a third fulltext column that's a composite of the client's ID, plus characters that won't be found in the fulltext rows, and include this third column in the total fulltext search. ugh.

Is it VERY VERY wrong to set up a unique table for each client, and just search on their table? The searches are very fast in my tests. How would this fair once you start needing more than one MySQL server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should give a look to this article:

```
http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/partitioning.html
```

and this one too:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html
```

The logic it's a little diffrent from "a table for each client", but It should fit to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Rookie question - most of my queries are by primary key, so I'd partition by that. However, some queries are also by date, and others 'genre'. Can I still set up indices for date and genre, as their data will be spread randomly throughout the partitions. Thanks.

Comment: @Shaun: Not sure if this answers to your doubt. Anyway, this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html, reports :

"Important
Partitioning applies to all data and indexes of a table; you cannot partition only the data and not the indexes, or vice versa, nor can you partition only a portion of the table."

Answer (score 1):

In general, partitionning is to be preferred over manualy splitting the data over multiple tables. There are a few caveats with partitioning to be aware of. In particular, [foreign keys are not supported](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations.html).

For your specific use case, there is one reason why you would want to take the "manual splitting" route: separating [statistics for your fulltext searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> Relevance is computed based on the number of words in the row, the
>   number of unique words in that row, **the total number of words in the
>   collection, and the number of documents (rows) that contain a
>   particular word**.

If all data is stored in one signle table (be it partitionned or not), the data belonging to one given user impacts relevance scores of all users.

Obviously, this does not apply if you never order your search results by relevance (i.e. if you just look up for boolean matches).